# Deserializing An Unknown JSON Format

Tags: c#, json.net

**EDIT:** My bad bros, I meant deserializing not serializing...

I am trying to interpret the JSON response I get from a website, but there are a two problems:

1) First version of the JSON has a list of an unknown number of strings, and I don't think I can create a class with a `List<string> {get; set;}` member.

2) I cannot know which version I will receive and in order to tell I will have to check for the value of `"Second"`. I am wondering if there may be an easier way to doing this?

These are the two possible formats:

```
{ "1":"1", "2":"2", "Second":{ "3":"3", "4":"4", "Third":["5"]}} <-- More things could be in 'Third'
{ "1":"1", "2":"2", "Second":{ "3":"3", "4":"4", "Third":{"5":"5", "6":"6"}}
```

I deserialize them using Newtonsoft's Json C# package and I receive the response from a `HttpClient.PostAsync()` call.

Comment: so it is only the value that is diferent in third, it could be array or key/values or some thing else, you need to write your customized class for newtonsoft deserializer, and make a conditional deserlization ( https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: This is how Third could be: `"Third:["5","6","7"]`. So it could basically hold multiple values, without keys. I tried using a List for it, but I cannot have the get and set parameters for it.

Comment: it could be arrays of values OR keys and values, YES, you need a custom class extending of JsonConverter class, I might be able to write it when i am done with my work today, if some body else do it fine with me.

Comment: [Deserializing an unknown type in JSON.NET](//stackoverflow.com/a/21246677)

Comment: Yeah, just mentioning that I did not see keys being used, but yeah. I need a way to store any number of values/keys and values that I receive

Answer (score 1):

Deserialising to a list should work ok. As @maytham says, a custom converter is the way to go.

The `SpecialArrayConverter` below should do the trick if you apply it to your model via the `[JsonConverter(typeof(SpecialArrayConverter))]` attribute.

As implemented below it'll read a dictionary or array in the json and populate the corresponding collection in the deserialised class.

I've typed the property as `IEnumable<string>` out of habit, but `List<string>` work just as well.  string[] can work with a bit of tweaking too.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Json
{
    class JsonResponseObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // Apply our special converter to this property
        [JsonConverter(typeof(SpecialArrayConverter))]
        public IEnumerable<string> ArrayData { get; set; }
    }

    // Our Special Converter
    class SpecialArrayConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        // Read Only
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        // We only work with IEnumerable<string> && IDictionary<string, string>
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<string>)) || objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDictionary<string, string>));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token;

            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                // If it's an array, read the token parse it
                // into an array and proceeed
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    token = JToken.Load(reader);
                    return token.ToObject<List<string>>();

                // If it's an object, it must be a dictionary
                // parse it into a dictionary and then
                // output the keys into an array and
                // return that
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    token = JToken.Load(reader);
                    var data = token.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                    return data
                        .Select(data => data.Key)
                        .ToList();
                default:
                    throw new JsonSerializationException();
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                ArrayData = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "5", "5" },
                    { "6", "6" }
                }
            });
            var b = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                ArrayData = new List<string>
                {
                    "5",
                    "6"
                }
            });

            var resulta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponseObject>(a);
            var resultb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponseObject>(b);

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was mentioning to OP. Good job ;)